# Web API change schema names

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net (get) web API that is being consumed using by both JSON and XML clients. Is there any type of attribute that I can decorate my code with that will change the various XML schema and JSON object names?

```cs
[WhatGoesHere("Record")]
public class AbcRecord
{
    public bool IsVaid { get; set; }
    [WhatGoesHere("Items")]
    public IEnumerable<AbcItem> AbcItems { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<Record xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MobilePortal.Library">
  <IsVaid>true</IsVaid>
  <Items>
    ...
  </Items>
</Record>
```

Or the equivalent JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the default XML and JSON formatters for Web API support DataContract and DataMember attributes. So your type would look like this:

```cs
[DataContract(Name = "Record")]
public class AbcRecord
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsVaid { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Items")]
    public IEnumerable<AbcItem> AbcItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this attribute on your class(es) to customize the namespace:

```cs
[DataContract(Namespace="http://example.com/namespace")]
```

I don't think any namespace is included in JSON by default so this attribute won't affect that.

Comment: I though you were asking about how to change the schema namespace, not the element names. [@Youssef's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16950229/346561) is correct for changing element names in both XML and JSON.